# Flutter: Using Stream with FirestoreListView

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Newer to flutter and I am trying to use a stream with the `FireStoreListView` widget, but I cannot quite figure out how to do so. I need a stream because I need to documents to update on change.

Stream is:

```
 final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _postsStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').orderBy('created_time').snapshots();
```

The using FirestoreListView

```
FirestoreListView(
query: _postsStream,
itemBuilder: ,
)
```

I am getting the following error

```
The argument type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Query<dynamic>'.
```

The `FirestoreListView` widget is looking for `Query<dynamic>` and I am not sure how to do that with a `Stream`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Because `FirestoreListView#query` is working with `Query` type but not with the `Stream`.
Just delete `snapshots` method from your query:

```
final _postsQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('posts')
                              .orderBy('created_time');
```

And use it directly in `FirestoreListView`:

```
FirestoreListView(
  query: _postsQuery,
  itemBuilder: (_, document) { ... },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`FirestoreListView` provides real time updates, so you don't need a `Stream` of your own to keep the list updated.
Just pass on your `query` and it will suffice.